# JSONDecodeError while reading JSON

Tags: python

I am trying to load a JSON file in Python for a machine learning assignment.
I am getting the error

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 1 (char 368)
```

[image: Code Attempted]

[image: JSON FILE TO BE IMPORTED]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post images of code (they are unusable), post a proper MCVE instead (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: FWIW your "json" file is not valid json indeed. Looks like json-lines (http://jsonlines.org/) but I can't say if that was on purpose or if it's an error from whoever created this file.

Comment: Your entries ("key": "value" pairs) should be separated with a comma inside the curly brackets. Looks like in one place this rule is broken - you can search it manually and correct it with a text editor.

Answer (score -1):

your json file is not in a valid json file format
please check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp
for more information